# Github commit, diff does not show changes

Tags: git, version-control, github, diff, commit

I recently made a commit to a repo on github and now when I want to see the differences, for one of the files all I get is:

`1273 additions, 678 deletions not shown`

What is the cause of this? How can I see the differences?

Comment: What commands are you using and what would you like to accomplish?

Comment: i am not using any commands, but the web interface itself. i want to see what the modifications to the file are

Comment: possible duplicate of [Large github commit diff not shown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702795/large-github-commit-diff-not-shown)

Comment: very helpful deleting everything. i still don`t know what causes this and what i can do to prevent it in the future. sarcastic thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Github doesn't show large diffs probably because it is quite js-intensive and will likely freeze your browser. Solution would be to not rely on github for browsing diffs which you can see in any git-gui you have

e.g. [tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/screenshots/diff-view.html) is pretty handy.

```
$ tig commithash
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the diff from your local machine if GitHub cannot show it to you

```
 $ git show the-commit-id path/to/the/file
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that answer myself, github fails to show me large diffs, so the solution was [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/).