# github Diff Truncated error

Tags: git, github, git-branch, pull-request

While making pull request in github and  reviewing changes we got Diff Truncated error as shown below

[image: diff truncated error]

Can anyone help to fix this issue

Comment: Is it possible that this file has a very large line, or trigger one of the limits mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14960810/6309?

Comment: it may be pull request has +20,932  −825 lines changes in branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible the pull request triggers one of the limits mentioned by [GitHub support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14960810/6309).

> [Brian Levin @github](https://github.com/dreamwire):
>
> We have some limits on diffs that we show in the browser in order to keep the pull request and compare pages working. Currently, we cut them off at:
>
> - 300 files,
> - a total diff of 1MB,
> - and an individual diff of 100KB.
>
> If your diffs exceed the limits and can't be viewed online, you can always pull the changes locally and view the diff there. It may not be as convenient for you, but it'll get the job done.

The [OP gyanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687021/gyanu) confirms:

> it may be pull request has +20,932 −825 lines changes in branch

One solution would be to request the contributor to split his/her PR into multiple smaller PR.

The other, as mentioned, is to pull everything locally, and work with the diff there.