# How to comment on long github diff

Tags: github

One of the files in a pull request that I'm currently reviewing has too many changes and github only shows the summary about deletions and additions.

This is rather unfortunate, since I can't comment on the changes that happened in this file. Is there any way to **force** github to show the diff for this one file in the PR **and** enable the comment functionality?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force it to comment from the browser, but you can workaround it to create the comment and have someone see it.

In [Large github commit diff not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14960810/641451), they say a Hubber said:

> We have some limits on diffs that we show in the browser in order to keep the pull request and compare pages working.

As of today, [GitHub's help](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-limits-for-viewing-content-and-diffs-in-my-repository/) still states there are (bigger) limits.

If you know the lines you want to comment you could [use GitHub's API to create the comment](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/comments/#create-a-commit-comment). I don't know if that comment will show on the diff page (I don't think so, as there won't be a diff at all), but you will certainly see it on the comments tab, as usual.